# Remove Image object from memory

Tags: javascript

The code below is triggered once every 100 ms:

```
  videoDecoder.onmessage = function (e) {
    let blob = e.data;
    let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      dCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    img.src = blobURL;
  };
```

Code works as expected, the problem is after a while about 30 mins to 1 hr or runtime, browser starts to get unresponsive and eventually crash. The idea is that this code is expected to run for more than 8 hours, even 24/7; what would be the best approach so it won't consume memory much as time goes? (that is what I have observed.)

Comment: You always want a single image object, why not create it and set the onload handler in the same place you declared dCtx? 4 lines of code removed from that function and then you just have to rely on GC for the pixel buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Revoke your `blob:` URLs!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL)

If you fail to do so, the browser has to keep the Blob alive and won't be able to release the memory it uses, since it can't know what you did with the string that points to it.

```
videoDecoder.onmessage = function (e) {
  const blob = e.data;
  const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    dCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
  };
  img.src = blobURL;
};
```

And you could even be nicer to the browser by instead using the [ImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap) API for that operation, which offers a [`.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap/close) method allowing to mark its data as revocable where it's harder to determine for `<img>`, since browser generally like to cache image data.

```
videoDecoder.onmessage = async function (e) {
  const blob = e.data;
  const bmp = await createImageBitmap( blob );
  dCtx.drawImage(bmp 0, 0);
  bmp.close();
};
```

Comment: This is only for  Firefox? When running on Chrome it throws: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The source image could not be decoded.`

Comment: What's in your Blob?

Comment: I run the app for 8 hours and it did not crashed, both worked.  Except that I have to check if the browser is Chrome or Firefox since `  const bmp = await createImageBitmap( blob );` wont work in Firefox, but works on Chrome. If it's Chrome have to deal with the data URL and just remove the URL afterwards.

Comment: That should work in both FF and Chrome or neither... What kind of image is it? Where does it come from?